# Updating all objects in a class

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm very new to using OOP in Python.
I have a problem to solve, that I was able to solve it partially. And sorry if I cannot make my question very clear.

If I create a object `test` of a class `ClassTest` and type in Python

```
test.__dict__
```

I will have the following result:

```
{'W0': 41.95659301705824, 'right': 'Seq1', 'W1': 86.66314873856487, 'left': <__main__.BranchLength object at 0x1083f8110>}
```

and if I again type:

```
test.left.__dict__
```

I will have:

```
{'W0': 86.66314873856487, 'right': 'Seq2', 'W': 41.95659301705824, 'left': <__main__.BranchLength object at 0x1083f8150>}
```

and so on...

Is there a way to interactively access ALL instances(?) of `left`? I'm interested in changing all values for `W0`, for example.

Thanks!

Comment: I feel that whatever you are trying to do, you are doing it the wrong way. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to walk through a tree? I.E. starting with some object, going to its member called `left` and if this member again has a member `left` go on and on and on?

Comment: A common pattern is to have a class variable to keep track of all instances; `__init__` will add `self` to `instances` and `__del__` will correspondingly remove it. Now accessing all instances is a trivial loop over `instances`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested, this looks like a [tree (or a graph) traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

You might want to look at [recursive algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_algorithm). For instance:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, child = None):
        self.x = x
        self.child = child

    def increments(self):
        self.x += 1 # increment this one
        # Check that the child is not 'None' or some other value
        if hasattr(self.child, 'increments'):
            # recursively increment the child
            self.child.increments()

    def __repr__(self):
        # friendly representation
        return 'A(%r, %r)' % (self.x, self.child)


>>> a = A(1, A(2, A(3, A(4))))
>>> a
A(1, A(2, A(3, A(4, None))))
>>> a.increments()
>>> a
A(2, A(3, A(4, A(5, None))))
>>> a.increments()
>>> a
A(3, A(4, A(5, A(6, None))))
```

Basically, you define your recursive function `X` as:

1. do something with the internal state of your object
2. do `X` with any dependent object (e.g. its child(ren))

**-- EDIT --**

Regarding your last comment to update only the last value (for a tree, this is called a *leaf*): you have two solutions:

One is to have the same kind of node for all your graph, and have leafs defined as 'node with no children':

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, x, *children):
        self.x = x
        self.children = []
        if children:
            self.children.extend(children)

    def updateLeafs(self, newx):
        if self.children:
            # This node has children: it is not a Leaf
            for c in self.children:
                c.updateLeafs(newx)
        else:
            # This node has no children -> Definition of a leaf !
            self.x = newx

    def __str__(self):
        "Pretty printing of the tree"
        if self.children:
            # A node
            return 'Node(%s -> [%s])' % (repr(self.x), ','.join(str(c) for c in self.children))
        else:
            # A leaf
            return 'Node(%s)' % repr(self.x)
```

And you get:

```
>>> tree = Node(1, Node(4, Node(4, Node(4), Node(5)), Node(6), Node(7, Node(8))))
>>> print tree
Node(1 -> [Node(4 -> [Node(4 -> [Node(4),Node(5)]),Node(6),Node(7 -> [Node(8)])])])
>>> tree.updateLeafs(10)
>>> print tree
Node(1 -> [Node(4 -> [Node(4 -> [Node(10),Node(10)]),Node(10),Node(7 -> [Node(10)])])])
```

The other possibility is to have distinct types for your leafs and your branches:

```
class Branch(object):
    def __init__(self, *children):
        self.children = children

    def update(self, newx):
        for c in self.children:
            c.update(newx)

    def __str__(self):
        "Pretty printing of the tree"
        return 'Branch([%s])' % (','.join(str(c) for c in self.children))

class Leaf(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def update(self, newx):
        self.x = newx

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Leaf(%s)' % self.x
```

And this yields:

```
>>> tree = Branch(Branch(Branch(Leaf(4), Leaf(5)), Leaf(6), Branch(Leaf(8))))
>>> print tree
Branch([Branch([Branch([Leaf(4),Leaf(5)]),Leaf(6),Branch([Leaf(8)])])])
>>> tree.update(10)
>>> print tree
Branch([Branch([Branch([Leaf(10),Leaf(10)]),Leaf(10),Branch([Leaf(10)])])])
```

The former allows for dynamic leafs (i.e. you can add new children to leafs later, which makes them stop being leafs), while the latter makes more sense if your tree node and leafs are intrinsically different (e.g. for a filesystem, where your leafs are file and the tree is a directory structure). It really depends on your problem to choose which is best.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I think this is exactly what I need to do. I am working with a type of graph. I will need to have something like ('A':c, 'B':c):b, 'C':(c+b)):c, 'D':'(c+b+a). Where a, b, and c are float. This is a simulation. So first I will have ('A':a, 'B':a).... then I will have (('A':b, 'C':b):a, 'B':(b+c)).. and so on... so I think your solution will work... I will try to implement it and I will let you know!! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help ! There is a lot of documentation on Graph traversals on the internet, so you should be able to find a lot of doc. The main pitfall when updating graphs recursively is to end up in a loop A<->B where you get A updates -> B updates -> A updates -> B updates -> ... but its easy to avoid once you know it :)

Comment: Hi! Do you mind explaining what exactly this "hasattr" is doing? I have searched for this information but I could not find a answer that I could understand. In your example: "if hasattr(self.child, 'increments')". self.child is an attribute in class A, right? But what is "increments" referring to? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. This `hasattr` checks whether its first argument _has_ an _attr_ibute with the given name. I do not check the type of the child directly (although it is possible), I only check that it has a `increments` method before I call the `increments` method. This is called duck typing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Instead of restraining myself to objects of type `A` (e.g. by typing `if type(self.child) == A`) I accept ANY type with an `increments` method.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I am still having problems to increments some of the numbers I need to (but I am almost there). Imagine for example: using your example, imagine if you have a = A(1, A(4, A(4, A(4)))) and you just want to update the very last number (note that I add the same number 4 for the some of the other child). Is there a way of doing that? A quick and efficient way? I am working with a more complex example, but the rationality for just one child should work for more than one, right? In my example, for each of "internal node" I have four attributes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, and I have to guess what your classes `TestClass` and `BranchLength` look like. (In my example they are identical, but in your code surely not).

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class TestClass:
    def __init__ (self, W0, left):
        self.W0, self.left = W0, left

    def updateW0 (self, f):
        self.W0 = f (self.W0)
        if self.left and hasattr (self.left, 'updateW0'):
            self.left.updateW0 (f)

class BranchLength:
    def __init__ (self, W0, left):
        self.W0, self.left = W0, left

    def updateW0 (self, f):
        self.W0 = f (self.W0)
        if self.left and hasattr (self.left, 'updateW0'):
            self.left.updateW0 (f)

b0 = BranchLength ('branch zero', None)
b1 = BranchLength ('branch one', b0)
b2 = BranchLength ('branch two', b1)
test = TestClass ('the test', b2)

for x in [b0, b1, b2, test]: print (x.W0)
test.updateW0 (lambda x: '{} {}'.format (x, x) ) #whatever update you need
for x in [b0, b1, b2, test]: print (x.W0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two potential solutions. You could try keeping every instance of the `TestClass` class inside of a list, in addition to how you're nesting them now, and simply iterate over the list to perform the same manipulations on all of them.

This is a little clunky though, and a better solution might be to start with the "top level object", and use recursion to traverse the tree, manipulating each instance as you go. For example:

```
def change_attr(tree, target, new_val):
    setattr(tree, target, new_val)  
    # essentially the same as doing `tree.__dict__[target] = new_val`
    if tree.left is None:
        return
    else:
        change_attr(tree.left, target, new_val)
```

You would then pass in your instance of the `TestClass` class into the function by calling

```
change_attr(test, 'W0', 'foobar')
```

...and have every child branch inside of it update to the appropriate value.